# Supabase and Axios(patch): index row size 3040 exceeds btree version 4

Tags: javascript, axios, next.js, supabase

I'm having this trouble while sending a `patch` request from axios to supabase (nextjs application):

```json
{
    "message": "index row size 3040 exceeds btree version 4 maximum 2704 for index \"guests_list_qr_code_url_key\"",
    "code": "54000",
    "details": "Index row references tuple (1130,6) in relation \"guests_lists\".",
    "hint": "Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed.\nConsider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing."
}
```

I'm just updating a `qr_code` field sending a very short `data:image` value in the body, but is throwing me that error.

`Body object`

```json
{
    "qr_code": "data:image/png;base64,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"
}
```

I implemented the same process using the supabase-js library in another project (website), and it's working good.

Need some clues on this.

**UPDATE!**

I found out that it's failing also if I use supabase-js in client side, but if I do the same in server side it works for both supabase-js and axios. Strange.

Then, that makes me wonder if it is a real problem related to my database.

Why this difference if the request is coming from the client-side or not?

**UPDATE 2!**

The problem is that the QR (image) generated is larger in client-side than server-side. I have compared both.

```json
{
  equals: false,
  qr_fe_length: 2918,
  qr_be_length: 1774
}
```

I'm using this module: https://github.com/soldair/node-qrcode

```js
const qr_code = await QRCode.toDataURL("34624727-f4f8-43d1-95d9-b5887be65da3")
```

I'm always storing a `uuid` hash inside that field.

I have used the same line of code to generate the QR `data:image` for both client-side and server-side.

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25138/index-max-row-size-error/25140#25140

Comment: I think isn't related to the database. I added an update to the initial post. Please check it out.